# Can I change what context is used to inject my handler?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, rcp, e4

Our e3/e4 RCP application consists of a bunch of components with model fragments. Before the upgrade to e4 we had *Guice* modules in each of the components to inject members into the class.

Currently we have set up a superclass to detect custom DoExecute and DoCanExecute annotations that uses the ContextInjectionFactory to invoke these methods with a custom context.

Example:

```
        IEclipseContext subContext = (IEclipseContext) context.get(contextName);
    return (T) ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(this, annotation, subContext);
```

This succeeds in using a specific context to inject members while executing the methods we have created annotations for, but is a little ugly and will have to be done for all annotations that inject in e4.

What is the best way in e4 to define and use a custom context? Note: We do not want to use the IApplicationContext as it would go against the modular setup per component.

Comment: I'm note sure I understand the question. Normally you use the current context for the part and possibly a second temporary context using the version of `invoke` which takes two contexts.

Comment: @greg-449 my main issue is I do not know how to separate contexts of various modules from each other neatly. Some interfaces may be implemented by multiple modules, but the implementation could be module-specific. Once a handler's canExecute is called, how do I make sure it also uses that custom context, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEclipseContext is managed by the Eclipse4 framework in a hierarchic fashion. Usually, you have the ApplicationContext as parent context, and then a hierarchy of child contexts, for example Workbench > Window > Perspective > Part.

Given my experience in E4 development, in the case of a multi-module application, I would store my model objects in the ApplicationContext, using different keys.

Let me explain: the IEclipseContext is an hashtable where you can store multiple objects using different keys. So, each module (fragment, or bundle) in your system, can persist its model data into the IApplicationContext using a different key.

As an example, if you have threee modules, in your system where one is the platform and two are simply "module1" and "module2", you can store the data of each module, in the application context, as follows:

```
**KEY**                 **VALUE**
org.myapp.platform  Java Object representing data model of the platform
org.myapp.module1   Java Object representing data model of the module1
org.myapp.module2   Java Object representing data model of the module2
```

By the way, if you are concerned about the data exposed in the context, you could delete a context object, by setting a null value in correspondence of a specific key.

Hope this helps.

You can dig deeper looking at the following references:

- Interface [IEclipseContext API](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fe4%2Fcore%2Fcontexts%2FIEclipseContext.html)
- EclipseSource [Eclipse4 Dependency Injection Basics](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-4-dependency-injection-basics/)
- Eclipse Wiki [Eclipse4 Dependency Injection](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection)
- Vogella's [Article on Eclipse 4 and DI](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextUsage/article.html)
- Brian's presentation on [Advanced use of Eclipse4 DI Framework](https://www.eclipsecon.org/na2014/sites/default/files/slides/2014-EclipseCon-DI.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It feels very close - but I'm missing a piece. If there's an 'SomeInterface' implemented by module1 and module2, how would the key look for these? How would you do inject a SomeInterfaceImpl instance in a Handler?

Comment: Here is my suggestion to inject your own object/services: 
1. Initial injection of your ContextServices or your ContextObjects in the Application Lifecycle class (or plugin lifecycle class)
2. Access your context objects (or services) in your Handler in the injected methods, @execute method (as an example)